# Autofac does not pass a instance of object Resolved using xml (Refection API) in web API

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, dependency-injection, autofac

I have a webapi controller where in the constructor has 2 parameters. I am using the autofac as the DI container. The RegisterAutofac() is the function called in the global.asax of the web api project

```
private static void RegisterAutofac()
{
    var builder = new ContainerBuilder();
    // Register the Web API controllers.
    builder.RegisterApiControllers(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly());
    // get the first param via xml
    builder.RegisterModule(new ConfigurationSettingsReader("autofac"));
    // get the 2nd param directly
    builder.Register(c => new Assets()).As<IAssets>().InstancePerLifetimeScope();

    // Build the container.
    var container = builder.Build();

    // Create the depenedency resolver.
    var resolver = new AutofacWebApiDependencyResolver(container);

    // Configure Web API with the dependency resolver.
    GlobalConfiguration.Configuration.DependencyResolver = resolver;

    //Register Autofac ends
}
```

When I run the controller , i can see that the first param is null and the 2nd one has a valid value. In the debug mode, I can verify that the first param ( using container.Resolve<>() ) has a valid value . Not sure why the autofac does not pass the dependency as a valid object to the controller when it is able to resolve it in the global.asax.

Comment: What does the xml look like? And what does the controller look like? You have to provide a complete scenario or else it is very difficult to help out

Comment: Hi Peter, The controller looks like this. public class AssetsController : ApiController 
    {
        IAssets asset;
        IValidate validate;
        public AssetsController(IAssets _asset,IValidate _validate)
        {
            asset = _asset;
            validate = _validate;
        }

Comment: ...and yeah, update your question instead of "hiding" vital stuff in comments. Read up on http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask it gives good advice on how to write good questions on SO